# Elastic Beanstalk Error on running eb init

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Below is the error every time I choose a region. 
- Already setup IAM and have set role to Administrative permission.
- Already did aws configure and input id and secret key.
- It's been weeks of digging and no solution so far :-( ..helpppp

ERROR: ServiceError - 'eb' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=sudo eb init/20181010/us-east-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=cfa71c2fdc34b31f2dae28283ab467229871338ac7cff6f447f99bcc6d43ed12'.

Comment: can you please tell me. How you set the aws access key and id ?

Comment: Thanks for replying..                                                              
in the command line.. 
- aws configure
- AWS Access Key ID [****************JUQQ]: <i write my IAM user access key id>
- AWS Secret Access Key [****************latK]: <i write my IAM user secret key id>
- Default region name [us-east-2]: 
- Default output format [json]: 
and did "eb init" and again choose a region.. after that - it output the ERROR above

Comment: Already fixed the issue. i make sure the aws config is set properly by checking both.
$ open ~/.aws/credentials
$ open ~/.aws/config
Editing the configuration to its correct Access and Secret Key..
Problem Solved :-)